# 'È strano come ...' vs. 'È strano *di* come ...'

Tags: prepositions

> 1) È strano come una deportazione appaia, grazie alla propaganda manovrata dagli intellettuali, un'azione umanitaria.
>
> 2) È strano *di* come una deportazione appaia, grazie alla propaganda manovrata dagli intellettuali, un'azione umanitaria.

La 1) appare grammaticalmente ineceppibile, ma sono quasi certo che la 2)—quella con il *di*—si usi comunemente.

La domanda è: È corretta o accettabile la 2)? O si deve necessariamente usare la 1)?

Comment: Definisci “comunemente”, Elberich. La 2) non credo di averla mai vista o sentita. Hai qualche esempio esistente?

Comment: Dopo "è strano" io mi aspetterei un complemento oggetto (*che cosa* ti risulta strano) mentre un complemento di specificazione è sicuramente inudibile e molto probabilmente errato.

Comment: @dag Su Google Libri esistono almeno una decina di occorrenze di "strano di come", mentre sul web—fra cui Wikipedia—centinaia, ma è nel parlato che quel ‘di’ si sente spessissimo.

Comment: Molte istanze di “strano di come” vengono da altre espressioni (“è più strano di come pensassi” e simili). Gli altri casi mi suonano molto strani e non me li spiego. Attenzione alle generalizzazioni del tipo “si sente spessissimo”: ognuno di noi frequenta altri parlanti abbastanza delimitati dal punto di vista geografico, sociale, dell'età e così via. Nessuno di questi insiemi limitati è intrinsecamente migliore o peggiore di un altro, ma nessuno è in genere rappresentativo dell'uso generale e tanto meno dell'italiano standard (a meno che uno non sia amico personale di Pietro Bembo :-) ).

Comment: @black, per essere pignoli, dopo “è strano” ci aspettiamo il soggetto del predicato nominale “è strano”: “è strano il modo in cui...”, “è strano che tu faccia così e cosà” etc.

Comment: Non riesco a dare conferme sulla correttezza grammaticale, ma la seconda versione suona male al mio orecchio.. e personalmente non l'ho mai sentita, se non in casi simili a quello citato da DaG.

Comment: Concordo _in toto_ con @DaG. Occorre prestare molta attenzione a ciò che si sente in giro, specialmente se, da stranieri che stanno imparando la lingua, si può essere tratti in inganno da un’errata segmentazione della frase.

Comment: La seconda può essere corretta in altri contesti, ad esempio quando una virgola precede la proposizione seguente, e.g. "E' strano, di per sé [...]" come suggerisce questa [Ricerca Google](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22%C3%A8+strano+di+*%22) che apparentemente non mostra casi di utilizzo simili a quello della domanda.

Comment: Personalmente non ho mai sentito "è ... strano di come" se non in situazioni in cui quel 'di' introduce un termine di confronto. Un consiglio che posso dare all'OP è di non analizzare la lingua selezionando sottostringhe arbitrarie, altrimenti c'è il rischio di chiedere "si può dire 'se accetterebbe'?" avendo letto "se accetterebbe volentieri un nuovo lavoro, perché non offrirglielo?".

Comment: Altro caso derivante da un "parsing" sbagliato: "fornì una spiegazione strana di come fosse riuscito a superare quell'esame"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Le proposizione completive soggettive rette dal verbo *essere* in unione con un aggettivo o un avverbio sono introdotte da *che* o da *come* nel costrutto esplicito. Non sono possibili altri introduttori.

> È strano **come** una discesa, vista dal basso, **assomigli** a una salita.
>   [Citazione spuria di Pippo.]

«*È strano di come una deportazione appaia…» è dunque agrammaticale.

Il costrutto implicito, invece, generalmente non richiede alcun introduttore:

> Che non **è giusto aver** ciò ch'uom si toglie [Esempio dalla voce «[Giusto](http://www.tommaseobellini.it/#/items/53514)» del Tommaseo-Bellini]

In passato, però, erano frequenti casi di reggenza preposizionale dell’infinito. Il Serianni (Luca Serianni, *Italiano*, Milano: «Garzanti», 2000, § XVI.72) afferma che questo tipo di costrutto «non [può] dirsi desuet[o] neppure nella prosa contemporanea», e porta poi alcuni esempi letterari dei secoli passati (ne riporto un paio):

> i quali fatti combinati **è affatto impossibile** alla mente umana
>   **d’intendere** [Vico, *Scienza nuova*, 137]
>
> voglio avvertirla d’una cosa che **le sarà utile di sapere** [Manzoni, *I
>   Promessi Sposi*, XIX 12]